# Will callback function gets executed only in error scenario - Passport SAML SSO

Tags: saml, passport-saml

I am learning about passport and working on SAML strategy, will this `(err) => {}` callback only run during case of error or it will run in all scenario, i.e successful, unsuccessful, error.
Thanks for any suggestions.

```js
passport.authenticate("saml", {
  failureRedirect: '/auth/login'
})(req, resp, (err) => {
  
});
```